# how to reduce distance between both text in listview?

Tags: android, listview, textview, distance

Hi I'm newly entered in this project. How to reduce listview text view distance please...

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1000dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"     
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: next time try to upload a lightweight picture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the below text.so it will set itself to the bottom of the layout.Either remove this and give marginTop to the this text or give marginTop to the above text.Here is only problem,look at it.

Use this XML as the list_item of your listview and make changes wherever needed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i dont know whether this is the only reqirement of yours though i have tried to shorten the distance between them.Try it n Hope this will help you.

Comment: sir still the problem not solved now i am updated my question i changed my xml textview marginTop but still its not working plz check and let me know sir